# GFortran: Read file bigger than 2GB

Tags: fortran, fortran90, gfortran, ftell

Does GFortran allow 8-byte integers as values for the read and inquire `pos=` argument?

Has GFortran an 8-byte version of ftell for getting file positions past 2GB?

The INTEL Fortran compiler has an 8-byte integer version of ftell called `ftelli8` but I don't find anything regarding Gfortran.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Fortran standard doesn't require specific integer kind as an `pos` argument to read. You can use any kind, including 8 bytes.

The GCC nonstandard function `ftell` returns kind 8 on my 64 bit system, which is an 8 byte integer in gfortran. You could easily check by a simple program

```
  print *, kind(FTELL(6))
  end
```

which prints 8, or

```
  print *, bit_size(FTELL(6))
  end
```

which prints 64.